# Wi-fi connectivity doesn't work in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, connection

I have a DELL Inspiron 6400 and I run Ubuntu 12.10 along side Windows 7.

The problem is that in Windows the wifi button works perfectly fine, the light can be turned on and off and so on, also the Internet works fine there.

But in Ubuntu I can't get the wifi to turn on. I event tried the additional driver tab in Software resources and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Update the System.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After this command try whether your wifi working or not. If not means do the following

Then you have to remove the bcmwl kernel source:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then again install :

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```